# Opening Access form with specific record selected keyed on date

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am creating a little app to track my sales activities and I am stuck on the form where I record data. I've spent about 9 or 10 hours so far researching and trying things, so I need a little help.

I have a table with records of how many sales calls, emails, meetings, proposals, etc., I made in a given day. "Date" is my primary key. The form should help me enter/edit the data.

My basic form looks like this:

Oops! Stack won't let me post images -- I can email it to anyone who asks
steve at hammerwings.com

There is a little calendar popup to select a different date for data entry:

Oops! Stack won't let me post images -- I can email it to anyone who asks
steve at hammerwings.com

I can select a new date in the popup, and when I click on the "Set Date" button it will
(1) Save the record in the tracked items form
(2) Close the tracked items form
(3) Reopen the tracked items form and set the date to the date I selected in the popup.

The problem is that it wants to create a NEW record with that date instead of editing the existing record. My existing data is not loaded, and I get a duplicate primary key error when I save.

Here is what does not work:

(1)
Form_DailyItemsTracked.Date = CalObject.Value
'This changes the date in the parent form without refreshing any of the data

(2) Close then reopen the parent form with the record selected
This opens the parent form with the date set, but does not load the existing record--it still wants to create a new record

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "DailyItemsTracked", , , "Date = " & CalObject.Value
```

(Date is the name of the field in the table)

These all throw some type of syntax error. MyDate is the name of the text box on the form controlled by the Date field. I have verified that CalObject.Value is correctly set in the popup, and that it is in ShortDate format, the same as the MyDate text box and the Date field.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "DailyItemsTracked", , , "[MyDate] = '" & Format(CalObject.Value, "Short Date") & "'"

DoCmd.OpenForm "DailyItemsTracked", , , "[MyDate] = " & Format(CalObject.Value, "Short Date")

DoCmd.OpenForm "DailyItemsTracked", , , "[Date] = " & CalObject.Value

DoCmd.OpenForm "DailyItemsTracked", , , "Tracked_items.[Date] = " & CalObject.Value

DoCmd.OpenForm "DailyItemsTracked", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal, CalObject.Value

DoCmd.OpenForm "DailyItemsTracked", , , "MyDate = " & CalObject.Value
```

(3)

```
Forms!DailyItemsTracked.Requery
```

This also throws a syntax error.

(4) I have also created a query with the date as a parameter and controlled the form with the query. I can get it to open, but it still wants to create a new record.

(5) I added an autonumber field and made that the primary key, with a hidden control on the form. This got rid of the duplicate primary key errors, but it still was not loading existing data when I opened the form.

Is it impossible to open a form with a specific record selected? Or is it impossible to do if the date is the control?

Is there a whole different way to go about this that would be simpler?

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the date delimiter syntax wrong. Try this.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "DailyItemsTracked", , , "Date = #" & CalObject.Value & "#"
```

Comment: Format to year, month, day would not hurt if there is any possibility of a locale outside the US.